# How to Have a Title That is Larger Than "h1"?

Tags: html, title, font-size

How to have a title that is larger than h1?
I have made mt title size "h1" but I think that it is not large enough.
Is there a way to make the title even larger?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, with CSS. There is no hierarchically higher title than `h1`.

Answer (score 7):

To adjust the look of your site you will typically use CSS. You can define your various header sizes in a separate css file or inline for this instance like below:

```html
<h1 style="font-size: 50px">Your Text Here</h1>
```

I recommend you look into some CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/ is a decent starting point, friendly and interactive.

Comment: _... https://www.w3schools.com/ is a decent starting point...._ w3fools should NOT be your source for learning technical stuff It is of very poor quality having outdated and buggy tutorials

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You want the `font-size` to be larger? You can just specify it like that:

```
h1 {
  font-size: (x)px;
  font-weight: bolder;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use stylesheet to make it bigger e.g
`h1{ font-size:3rem;}`

You can specify the size and unit you want.